# Objective-C - Formatting GET request

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

What are the rules for passing the string parameter such as %JOHN% in a GET request url

my request url is supposed to look like: https://somesite.com/search/name?name=%SEARCH_KEYWORD%

Try#1: I did this

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://somesite.com/search/name?name=%%%@%%",SEARCH_KEYWORD]];
```

**O/P:** nil

Try#2:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://somesite.com/search/name?name=%JOE%"]];
```

**O/P:

```
https://somesite.com/search/name?name=JOE
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSURLComponents` to build URLs:

Objective-C:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"https://google.com"];
components.query = @"s=%search keywords%"

NSURL *url = components.URL;
```

Swift (careful with `!` in production, I used to test in Playgrounds):

```
let components = NSURLComponents(string: "https://google.com")!
components = "s=%search keywords%"

let url = components!
print(url) // "https://google.com?s=%25search%20keywords%25"
```

Also if you need more complex queries `NSURLComponent` have a `queryItems` property.

Answer (score -3):

You are making a mistake, just use a single `%@`. 
Example:

```
NSString *string = @"JOE";
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://somesite.com/search/name?name=%@",string]];
```